# No module named 'OpenSSL' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I search on google how to add OpenSSL in python. The command is easy to run.

`pip install pyOpenSSL` or `pip3 install pyOpenSSL`. I don't know if my OpenSSL is already installed. I have this response when I installed openssl.

```
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
Requirement already satisfied: pyopenssl in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (20.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyopenssl) (36.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyopenssl) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from cryptography>=3.2->pyopenssl) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=3.2->pyopenssl) (2.21)
DEPRECATION: Configuring installation scheme with distutils config files is deprecated and will no longer work in the near future. If you are using a Homebrew or Linuxbrew Python, please see discussion at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/76621
```

this is my index.py code

```
import base64
import json
import requests
from OpenSSL import crypto
```

when I run this command `python3 index.py`. I always get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenSSL'
```

May i know what's the issue in my setup? Im new in python code. My python version is `3.10.0`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `pyopenssl` installed for a Python 3.9 installation (look at the path: `/usr/local/lib/python3.9`), but you are trying to run with a Python 3.10 installation.

Use the `pip` from your Python 3.10 installation to install the required packages. `python3 -m pip install pyOpenSSL` should do that, regardless of what the standalone `pip` command resolves to.

Comment: `python3 -m pip install pyOpenSSL` should work without knowing...?

Comment: yes. I get the same issue if I run `pip install pyopenssl`

Comment: @user3818576 what about `python3 -m pip install pyOpenSSL`